# Parametric Plot from ODE using WhenEvent

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, event-detection

I am searching for a while now, but I don't seem to be able to find an Answer for my Problem - if I am just not able to search properly, I am really sorry.

I Simplified my Problem to the following example:

```
eqnA := {a''[x] + a[x] == b*Sin[a[x]]};
condA := {a[0] == a'[0] == 1};
stopCond := {WhenEvent[Evaluate[Re[a[x]] <= 0], xMax = x; "StopIntegration"]}
system := Join[eqnA, condA, stopCond];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[system, a, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {b}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[a[b][x] /. sol, {b, .8, 1.2, .05}], {x, 0, xMax},PlotRange -> All]
```

Now, the Plot I want to create is a Parametric Plot of a over xMax. (Yes, I understand, that in this example it would be just a line - if it is any help: I am trying to solve the TOV equations and create the Mass over Radius diagram with central density as parameter)

I think, my understanding of WhenEvent and the uses of it might be flawed.

Any Tips are appreciated!

Edit: Since I think I did not formulate my problem clearly enough I try to explain a bit further:

With the post from george2079 I was able to get a bit further, but It still does not work.

```
f[b_] := (a[b] /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 2]]
g[b_] := a[b][f[b]] /. sol
ParametricPlot[{f[b], g[b]}, {b, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I would expect that to produce something close to a line along the x-axis, but instead I get an error message. Plotting f[b] and g[b] individually works just fine.

Comment: By "Parametric Plot of a over xMax", do you mean a plot of the point `{xMax, a[b][xMax]}` as `b` varies?  Note that `a[b][xMax]` would approximately be zero.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. xMax[b] on the x-axis, on the y-axis a[b][xMax], and I am interested in the resulting line when varying b (in my simple example a straight line along the x-axis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WhenEvent` is just fine.  If you look at an individual solution you can see where it stopped:

```
            (a[.8] /. sol)["Domain"]
```

> {{0., 3.6351}}

The trouble is `Plot` extrapolates* past the solution domain, so you need to specify each plot domain individually:

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[ #[x] /. sol ,
    Evaluate[{x, Sequence @@ (First@#["Domain"])}],
    PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[]]] &@(a[b] /. sol) ,
     {b, .8, 1.2, .05} ], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Of course knowing whats going on you might just specify `PlotRange->{0,Automatic}` as well.

If you want to plot the stop point vs. `b` :

```
Plot[ (a[b] /. sol)["Domain"][[1, 2]] , {b, .8, 1.2}]
```

[image]

*and it really ought to throw a warning about it...

Edit: here is a parametric plot of the end value of each solution:

```
ParametricPlot[
  (Flatten@Last@Transpose[(a[b] /. sol)[{"Grid", "ValuesOnGrid"}]]),
       {b, .8, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, -1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

letting `ParametricPlot` autorange we can see the accuracy of the solver meeting your zero condition.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this already looks really useful! Maybe I can solve my Problem playing with "Domain".
But I think my question formulated a bit confusing (Sorry for that, english is not my native tongue). I tried to explain, that the Plot I really want to create would be something like:
    ParametricPlot[{xMax[b],a[b]},{b, .8, 1.2}]

Comment: responding to comment, `a[b]` at what `x`?  `a[b][xMax[b]]` is zero due to your `WhenEvent`

Comment: yes, a[b][xMax[b]] is zero in my example code, but in the Parametric Plot it should be a Line on the x-axis (since a is on the y-axis and because of my condition). Like I said, this is because i used a simplified ODE as example.
Since this causes a lot of confusion: My full system are the coupled Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff equations, with the WhenEvent triggered by the pressure reaching approx. 0 and the Plot should be the Mass at r=rMax over the max. of the Radius (which I get via the WhenEvent). 
But the problem is the same as in the example ODE that I used.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need!