# ParametricNDSolve&Extrapolation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a ODE system using Mathematica. In particular, I would like to see the numerical solutions with a parameter which can have different values. This is the code I have written

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{CovariantDE == 0, CovariantDM == 0, Gattopardo == 0, DM[0] == 0.25, DE[0] == 0.7, w[0] == -1}, {DM, DE,
w}, {t, -0.4, 0}, {c}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[DE[c][t] /. sol, {c, 1, 7, 1}]], {t, -0.4, 0}, PlotRange -> All]
```

what I obtain is

```
ParametricNDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 101438 steps reached at the point t == -0.346013.

ParametricNDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 101521 steps reached at the point t == -0.361499.

ParametricNDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 101809 steps reached at the point t == -0.298921.
General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolve::mxst will be suppressed during this calculation.

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-0.399992} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-0.399992} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

[image]

I would like to prevent mathematica from using interpolation: if the calcutions for the numerical solution "A" have been stopped at some point "xA", then I don't want Mathematica to use extrapolation. By the way, different values of the parameters means a different domain. Can you help me?

P.S: I looked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115339/parametric-plot-from-ode-using-whenevent/115345#115345)  on the site, but I didn't find nothing useful for me.

Edit:
here is the code you requested

```
CovariantDM = DM'[t] + 3 a'[t]/a[t] DM[t] + Q[t];

CovariantDE = DE'[t] + 3 a'[t]/a[t] DE[t] (1 + w[t]) - Q[t];

Gattopardo = w'[t]*Q[t] + DE[t]*w[t]

Q[t] = 2*c*DM[t]*Log[3*DM[t]/DE[t]]*a'[t]/a[t];
```

do you need something else? I am sorry I didn't write it before, I thought it wasn't necessary. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You will have to share all the code if you want people to be able to help you. Please, include the definitions of `CovariantDE`, `CovariantDM`, etc. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want it to use extrapolation, then don't ask it to plot data outside the computed range. So you'll either have to change/fix the `ParametricNDSolve` call to not fail/abort (which, as @AccidentalFourierTransform pointed out, we can only help you with if we have all definitions) or you could only plot the valid range. For that, note that `First@InterpolatingFunction[…]` gives the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction` object

Comment: Your real problem is `ParametricNDSolve::mxst`.  Solve it, and Mathematica will stop extrapolating.  Try increasing `MaxSteps`.